# Pandas read_csv incorrectly naming columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import a Leukemia gene expression data set found at https://www.kaggle.com/brunogrisci/leukemia-gene-expression-cumida. This data set has a lot of columns (22285) and the columns imported towards the end have an incorrect name. For example the last column named **AFFX-r2-P1-cre-3_at** is actually called **217005_at** in the csv file. The image below shows my juypter notebook cells. I am not sure why it is being formatted this way? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Python Code]

Comment: 22,285 columns is so, so many. There might just be a few too many or too few commas towards the end.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently the CSV file has column names that start with 'AFFX-r2-P1' -- it's not a pandas issue.  Using the built-in `csv` package shows:

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

data_file = Path('../../../Downloads/Leukemia_GSE9476.csv')

with open(data_file, 'rt') as lines:
    csv_file = csv.reader(lines)
    fields = next(csv_file)
#
[
    (field_number, field)
    for field_number, field in enumerate(fields)
    if field.startswith('AFFX-r2-P1')
]
```

The output is:

```
[(22277, 'AFFX-r2-P1-cre-3_at'), (22278, 'AFFX-r2-P1-cre-5_at')]
```